# Unable to use font-awesome in Laravel dompdf

Tags: font-awesome, dompdf

How do we embed fontawesome icons in laravel dompdf?

I added fontawesome via external css link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

and used it normally such `<i class="fal fa-lock"></i>`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored
```